# Wrong displaying spacial characters

Tags: html, angularjs

I have next code:

```
<div>
  {{message}}
</div>
```

When I am assigning next text ("some text") to `message` in page I am getting next text: `&#34;some text&#34;`. How I can configure it to display correct quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, your message is a String with the content ' "some text" '. In this case you will have to escape the special characters inside the String. It is ok to have javascript code, that looks like:

```
var message = '"some text"'
```

But when you want to display it in HTML you should try

```
var message = '\"some text\"'
```

Comment: It's not case for me, because text can have 1000+ words and other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

We need just use:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="message"></div>
```